# Python dictionary comprehension Scoping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nameerror, dictionary-comprehension

I am running the code below and getting a NameError.
When I run it one line at a time, it works, but when I wrap the lines inside a function, I get *NameError: name 'primes_cols' is not defined*. Why is the code below producing a NameError when the variables are defined?

```
import pandas as pd

primes = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A','B','C','D'], data=[[3,5,7,11]])
tens = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['E','F','G','H'], data=[[10,20,30,40]])
evens = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['I','J','K','L'], data=[[4,8,12,16]])

def process():
    keys = ['primes','tens','evens']
    
    # My Data
    data = {key:eval(key) for key in keys}
    
    # Trim Dataframes
    primes_cols = ['A','B']
    tens_cols = ['E','F']
    evens_cols = ['I','J']
    
    data = {key:value[eval(key + '_cols')] for (key, value) in data.items()}
    
    return data

df = process()
```

Comment: The issue is how `eval` works here, but you should avoid it entirely in this situation. Essentially, `eval` won't have access to any enclosing scopes. So it's `locals` consists entirely of the local variables inside the dictionary comprehension. You could  do something like `l = locals()` outside then use `eval(key + '_cols', gloabls(), l)` but **you shouldn't be using `eval` here at all to begin with**

Comment: `data = {key:eval(key) for key in keys}` is crazy. Don't do that  just do `values = [primes, tens, evens]` and `data = dict(zip(keys, values))`

Comment: so, you could just do `keys = ['primes','tens','evens']` and `values = [primes, tens, evens]` and `cols = [primes_cols, tens_cols, evens_cols]` then just do `return {key:df[c] for key,df,c in zip(keys, values, cols)}`

Comment: Thank you. I will avoid eval

Answer (score 0):

The best approach (@juanpa.arrivillaga), as seen in the comments, Is to avoid eval

```
import pandas as pd

primes = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A','B','C','D'], data=[[3,5,7,11]])
tens = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['E','F','G','H'], data=[[10,20,30,40]])
evens = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['I','J','K','L'], data=[[4,8,12,16]])

def process():
    # Trim Dataframes
    primes_cols = ['A','B']
    tens_cols = ['E','F']
    evens_cols = ['I','J']
    
    keys = ['primes','tens','evens']
    values = [primes, tens, evens]
    cols = [primes_cols, tens_cols, evens_cols]
    
    return {key:df[c] for key,df,c in zip(keys, values, cols)}
```